# Prism Template Pack isn't coming in Manage Extension in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, templates, prism

I need to create  an new WPF App using Prism Architecture, but in VS 2019, 2022,  "Prism Template Pack" template isn't coming. Please help me How could i start integrate Prism template for my WPF application.
Thanks in advance..!

Comment: I faced a similar issue where I could not install the Prism Template Pack on VS2019. A workaround I used was to clone/download zip of a sample prism project from github. I would recommend working on top of the ViewModelLocater sample project
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf

Answer (score 0):

From [Prism Documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/getting-started/productivity-tools.html), the template pack supports VS 19, and I am using it as well.

Anyway there are some [workarounds](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/discussions/2612) to make it works on 2022.

Personally I prefer to wait for it to be officially released.